# Flash german characters problem ä,ö

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I can't get flash to show ä,ö and ü in TextField.

`System.useCodePage = true;` 
does not help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a static or dynamic textfield? How are you putting the characters into the textfield?

Answer (score 2):

1. First check if the font-family you're using supports those chars.
2. If it does then you need to embed the font in order to get the chars displayed.

have fun ;P

Answer (score 0):

you have to embed those characters specifically in the text field
in the "additional characters" field when you click on embed on properties